# Change only touchpad speed?

Tags: windows-7, touchpad

I wonder is there any way to change touchpad speed/sensitivity, independent of mouse speed? I'm using Windows 7 x64 on an Asus K53U AMD laptop.
ASUS Smart Gesture has no options related to what I need.
At the moment in mouse settings I have set max cursor speed, it suits my needs really well when working on touchpad, but when I plug mouse in it is too fast and pointer speed must be decreased...

Update 1: I should add one more thing, I've just tried using "AutoSensitivity" but it doesn't work in my case, at all.

Update 2: Tried "Mouse Speed Switcher" as well, no matter which slider I move, for touchpad or mouse speed, they both slow down or speed up...

Hopefully some of you may help,
Dragoslav.

Answer (score 1):

Install the drivers for your touchpad if they are not installed and adjust it's sensitivity from within the touchpad tab in Control Panel --> Mouse.

Alternatively, install drivers for your mouse (logitech and Microsoft frequently have these) to adjust settings for your mouse independently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have installed drivers, they come with ASUS Smart Gesture. My mouse is HP, it has no separate drivers, using Windows generic drivers.

However, I managed to get it all working as I wanted using Mouse Speed Switcher.